# How Do I Handle Template Events When Multiple Template Instances Exist?

Tags: events, meteor, spacebars

I have same template included in 2 places with different parameters like that:

```
{{> newPost isReply=true replyTo=this}}
```

When I put breakpoint in helper method I see that this.isReply variable is indeed set to true, hoverer in events function it is false. I think that the reason is that there are several inclusion of same template and another one are where this flag is set to false and selector fits that template too and it is invoked so I get this data context inconsistency between templates. Here is selector example:

```
'click #savePost' : function() {
      if (this.isReply) {
      ....
```

My question is maybe someone can explain how exactly meteor works in such situation and how should approach such situation? Right now I think solution would be #savePost unique for each template, but I am interested if the way I am heading is even a good practice in meteor? Also as you understand *newPost* template contains button #savePost, how I should make it unique? I can't do:

```
'click #savePost' + someId : function() {
```

Comment: `this` in event handlers does not necessarily refer to the data context used to render the template. There should be no problem using multiple template instances as long as you're not changing variables in the enclosing environment. Can't you simple use classes instead of ids?

Comment: I see. What I am trying to do is a new post functionality, and I have template with button and popup to post. Right now there is one template for new post and each existing post have a template with replyTo=true, postId=id parameters. Don't know if its best practice to implement functionality like that. I can use classes or anything if it helps my goal :)

Comment: You want the parent template to listen for events occurred in the child template?

Comment: No, but it seems something like that happens. I have a template just to post new post (isReply=false), and then each existing post contains template to post reply. When i click on reply i want to set and use id of post to which user reply. So actually i want the oposite that each template would listen only to their events and i could use their data context which will contain isReply flag and postId to which user replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to access the data using `this`. The right way is to use the `Template.instance().data`. Example:

```
'click #savePost': function( e, tmpl ) {

  if ( tmpl.data.isReply )
    //do stuff.

}
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for an idea, however it's still the same. Because event selector fits all templates I guess meteor just uses first template to handle it which in my case has isReply flag set to false in its data context. At least that's what I suspect about how meteor works, and I am not sure how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if I'm understanding this correctly, you have multiple of the same `id`s on the page at the same time (multiple `#savePost`s) which is invalid html. Instead, you should make it a class (`.savePost`).

Regardless, you are allowed to have the same selector in multiple places, and Meteor can differentiate between them. In the event function, you have access to the data context and the target of the event.

For example:

```
Template.newPost.events({
    'click .savePost': function (event) {
        console.log(this); // this will return the data context
        console.log(this.isReply); // this should give you a correct value
        console.log($(event.target)); // this is how to select the button that was just clicked
        console.log($(event.target).val()); // this will give you the value
    }
});
```

This should work regardless of how many templates use the same class for a click event.